# ${a_n}$ non-convergent sequence such that $1\le a_n \le 2$. Prove or disprove: $\limsup a_n\cdot \limsup \frac 1 {a_n} \gt 1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let ${a_n}$ be a non-convergent (or divergent) sequence such that $1\le a_n \le 2$.

Prove or disprove:

$$\limsup a_n\cdot \limsup \frac 1 {a_n} \gt 1$$

**My try:**

$a_n$ must have at least two subsequential limits within the interval [1,2]. If that's the case then $\frac 1 {a_n}$ should have at least two subsequential limits within the interval $[\frac{1}{2}, 1]$. Thus, it follows that the inequality is true.

Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is pretty good, but I would note that since the limit does not exist,
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n\gt\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n
$$
and that
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac1{a_n}=\frac1{\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n\cdot\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac1{a_n}
=\frac{\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n}{\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n}\gt1
$$

Comment: Very elegant. +1

Comment: Where can I find a formal proof of this claim: $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac1{a_n}=\frac1{\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n}$?

Comment: @MisterBister: Suppose $a_n\gt0$. Then $$ \begin{align} \limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac1{a_n} &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\ge n}\frac1{a_k}\\ &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}\max_{n\le k\le m}\frac1{a_k}\\ &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac1{\min\limits_{n\le k\le m}a_k}\\ &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\min\limits_{n\le k\le m}a_k}\\ &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\inf\limits_{k\ge n}a_k}\\ &=\frac1{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\inf\limits_{k\ge n}a_k}\\ &=\frac1{\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n} \end{align} $$